# 忙しさもひと休みといったところだ。

Tags: meaning

I found this sentence: 忙しさもひと休みといったところだ。
And I cannot make it out anyhow.
Can anybody make it clear to me please?

Comment: Straight translation questions are generally not acceptable here. Is there a particular aspect of this that you're having trouble with? Your question will likely be closed in its current state so please try to edit it to ask something specific.

Comment: Divide and conquer.  Identify each part of the sentence, look it up if you don't understand it, then figure out how they fit together.  If you still don't understand, then as ssb said, you can ask about the specific part giving you trouble.

Comment: @user3195 I'm afraid this question is unlikely to be useful to future users in its current state, so I've closed it.  Please see [the FAQ](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/799/1478) for details.  If you'd like for your question to be re-opened, please take the time to read ssb's comment and follow his advice.

Answer (score 1):

It means that the current level of busyness is at a low ebb.

"isogashisa mo hitoyasumi to itta tokoro da"

The "to itta tokoro da" part is explained in the textbook you got the phrase from.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @user18597 's reading. One thing you can try is substituting another valid particle like は or が for も, and rereading it:

忙しさは、一休みといったところだ。

The phrase 〜といった can be thought of as a larger group, namely, （こ・そ・あ・ど）ういった.

Then all you have to do is combine that with 〜ところだ, and you can put the sentence together.